# Custom EditText just a line

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop

[image: Screen]

I want these type of text fields. I tried using android lollipop but I got black edit text. I want it in white colour . Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its based on the theme you are using..generally themes have the color you need to show, but you can always override them

Comment: Questions need to be more specific than "I want to do this; please help me" on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use black theme in lollipop and check. Other solution you can use white line in jpg and set it in xml of your edittext like:

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/white_line"
```